# Where did the marble procedural texture go? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

It seems to me that the procedural textures aren't render engine dependant, I guess I'm wrong. Does anyone know why this is?

Is there anyway to get a procedural marble texture into cycles? (or simulate it in some way?)

Comment: Hate to say it, but Cycles Wave is never near to either Marble or Wood in BI. Marble, for instance, has a great set of controls in BI, Wave in Cycles doesn't have them. Probably there are workarounds, but so far all my own attempts to get anything similar to BI Marble from Cycles Wave yielded zilch.

Comment: @YuriIlyin Do you have an example of the BI marble texture you want to simulate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wave Texture node has Distortion, Detail and Detail Scale controls that can be used to generate results like the Marble texture.

The textures are different because the whole shading system is different, we decided to redesign it entirely. Some texturing features from Blender internal are still missing because we haven't had time to add them back, we can't reuse the code directly because everything needs to be reimplemented for Cycles to work on the CPU, GPU and Open Shading Language.

Comment: So will the marble texture get reimplemented in cycles? or is the wave texture it?

Comment: The Wave texture is a replacement for both the Marble and Wood textures, so a separate Marble texture will not be added.

Answer (score 8):

In the Cycles rendering engine, both the Marble and Wood procedural textures are merged into a single texture known as 'Wave'.

You can use the Distortion and Detail settings to achieve the old Marbles look. One setup to achieve a look like the old Blender-Internal Marble texture is:

[image]

This returns a texture that looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is what I get for asking two questions.. I got two answers, but I can't accept both... :P

Comment: @gandalf3 looking at the question, it ***is*** possible to branch it off into another one. Since brecht already answered the first one, you could ask the second one again as a new question and a followup.

Comment: @iKlsR Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by branch of into a new question and a follow up

Comment: @gandalf3 no worries man. It has been dealt with accordingly, everyone gets to keep their rep, and you get both your answers! :)